# Will My iPhone App be Approved without a Default.png file ?

Tags: iphone, ios, default.png

Do I still need to include Default.png in my iPhone app or is Default@2x.png enough?

I see I can compile an app that only has Default@2x.png and Default-568h@2x.png, but will my app be approved for the App Store without Default.png?

Comment: Are you that concerned about the size of your app that you can't downscale your Default@2x and use it?

Comment: I think it will depend on whether you app supports non-retina devices or not. If your app targets iPhone 4 and above then I think it would be alright. Submit and answer your own question for us all :)

Comment: "Will My iPhone App be Approved If XYZ" questions ***cannot possible be answered by anyone here.*** Period. We don't know. Only Apple knows that.

Comment: @DanF Every byte counts!

Comment: I submitted an app a few days ago and did not have Default.png, so now I am trying to decide if I should reject and re-submit it.

Comment: @Chris If it made it past the initial checks, you are probably in the clear.  The presence of a Default.png is something that can be checked directly from the binary.  Although, as H2CO3 pointed out, since I do not work for Apple, I cannot guarantee that statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if it will be rejected, but I think it should be, according to Apple's guidelines. Your app is required to run on an iPad (even if it's an iPhone app), and an iPad mini or iPad 2 will run your app in non-retina resolution, so it should have a Default.png.

Answer (score 1):

The only way to know for sure is to wait and see.

Even if they approved somebody else's app without one, that doesn't mean that they will approve yours.

Even if they approve **your** app, that doesn't mean that they will approve the same app down the road when you submit an update.

That being said, if you only include the @2X version and run it on a non-retina device, it scales the @2X image down and displays it anyway.  It does not display a black screen.

If I had to **guess**, then I would say that it most likely won't be a problem because:

1. They don't require it
2. There is no warning generated without it (unlike the @2X)
3. It uses a scaled down version of the @2X image on a non-retina device if there isn't one for non-retina devices.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for us to know if your app will be rejected for any reason but I would say that as long as no automated checks caught this missing image you may be fine. The reason is that who is to say that a black screen when you start up the app wasn't intended. This is all just a guess though.